# Bootstrap navigation not working when page resizes for mobile

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

The tabs for switching between months on [this](http://www.macscampingarea.com/Home/Activities) page work when the page is at full size but once the page re-sizes for mobile they stop working. In the past I have had issues with the html data-toggle attribute in Bootstrap not working on a mobile device and so I had to switch to a strictly JavaScript approach with the JQuery methods provided by Bootstrap. I am hoping someone with deeper Bootstrap knowledge will know if there is something wrong with the data-toggle setup currently being used or if I will have to go back to the strictly JavaScript approach. The documentation for Bootstrap tabs is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

Below is the html for the tabs.

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="activityList">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="http://www.macscampingarea.com/Home/Activities#may" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">May</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="http://www.macscampingarea.com/Home/Activities#jun" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">June</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="http://www.macscampingarea.com/Home/Activities#jul" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">July</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="http://www.macscampingarea.com/Home/Activities#aug" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">August</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="http://www.macscampingarea.com/Home/Activities#sep" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">September</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="http://www.macscampingarea.com/Home/Activities#oct" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">October</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Please take note of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) reports several errors on your page. Fix them.